# How can I make overflowing text move in a direction instead of making it hidden

Tags: html, css

I have this html code which I want to move to the left if it's overflowing, it currently looks like this:

```css
.main section {
  font-size: 101%;
  color: #262626;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  display: block;
}
.main section b {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<section>
g'day, <b>captain</b><br />
</section>
<p>status: sunken</p>
</div>
```

it currently looks like this:

```
g'day captain
status: sunken
```

But I would prefer it look like this:

```
 g'day captain
status: sunken
```

Or if it were something really long, like this:

```
g'day captainamerica
      status: sunken
```

If still unclear I want to make the section text to move to the left if it's too long while the rest of the content stays put.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add &nbsp; in front of the text.
You can add padding-left to the section.
I am sure there are a variety of ways using CSS to achieve this.
I usually find the simplest method is the best.

Comment: nah mate I just had to use `text-align: left;`

Comment: but `text-align: left;` is doing the opposite thing than you want

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is `text-align: right;` or if you want to do something more complex use `flex` property:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-end;
```

in your example, you should get rid of the `margin-left` and `width` on each element. I've added `width` property to `main` class so you can see it's working.

```css
.main {
  text-align: right;
  width: 200px;
}

.main section {
  font-size: 101%;
  color: #262626;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.main section b {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section>
    g'day, <b>captain</b>
  </section>
  <section>
    g'day, <b>captain</b>america
  </section>
  <p>status: sunken</p>
</div>
```